# Handling different object types contained within the same set of elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML document that looks something like the following:

Note that I cannot change the schema because it is part of a standard XML Schema (Library of Congress METS).

```
<amdSec ID="AMDSEC001">
    <digiprovMD ID="DMD001">
        <mdWrap MDTYPE="OBJECT">
            <xmlData>
                <object xsi:type="file">
                    .....
                </object>
            </xmlData>
        </mdWrap>
    </digiprovMD>
    <digiprovMD ID="DMD001_EVENT">
        <mdWrap MDTYPE="EVENT">
            <xmlData>
                <event xsi:type="event">
                    .....
                </event>
            </xmlData>
        </mdWrap>
    </digiprovMD>
</amdSec>
```

As you can see, the inner element `<mdWrap>` can contain elements of different types; in this case they're `<event>` and `<object>`, but it isn't constrained to just those two types.  Creating two classes (like below), marshals okay, but this doesn't work for unmarshalling.

```
class ObjectMDWrap {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "xmlData")
    @XmlElement(name = "object")
    List<MyObject> object; //Wrapped in list to use @XmlElementWrapper
}

class EventMDWrap {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "xmlData")
    @XmlElement(name = "event")
    List<MyEvent> event; //Wrapped in list to use @XmlElementWrapper
}
```

What can I do so that JAXB unmarshals the correct "type" of MDWrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution, and it's much simpler than I initially thought (which speaks to my relative inexperience with XML and JAXB).  By creating my `MDWrap` class in the following way

```
class MDWrap {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "xmlData")
    Object wrappedMD;
}
```

Then `MDWrap` can contain an object of any type, and will unmarshal properly, as long as the class of which `wrappedMD` is an instance of is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.  The trick is to annotate `wrappedMD` as `XmlAnyElement`.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the best solution in this case is a generating POJO classes using [XJC](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) tool.

1. Download XSD file which describe XML file.
2. Using [XJC](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) tool convert XSD file into POJO classes. If XSD is not correct - fix it.
3. Make some changes if you need in generated classes.
4. Use this classes in marshalling / unmarshalling process.

Comment: I gave this a +1 because it lead me on the correct path of going back and looking at the actual XSD for METS that is provided by the LOC.  This also in itself is a reasonable solution.  However this isn't the solution I went with.